# dotnet command to remove all references from a project

Tags: .net-core, terminal, reference, project

What is a `dotnet` command to remove all references from a project?

I know that I can use the `dotnet remove reference <PROJNAME>` to remove a single reference. But What if I want to remove them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation says wildcards are supported by `dotnet remove reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-remove-reference), but they didn't seem to work for me on dotnet 3.1.100 preview 3.

I just use the shell (on Linux) to do this:

```
dotnet remove reference $(dotnet list reference | tail -n +3)
```

That calls `dotnet list reference` to find all the project-to-project references, then pipes them to `tail` to remove the headers from the output, and then passes the resulting list of project-to-project references to `dotnet remove reference` to remove them all.

Comment: powershell alternative: dotnet list reference your_project.csproj | select -skip 2 | Foreach-object{dotnet remove reference $_}